# VBA certain Part of a String

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have an excel column with strings like this one: ABC-1234-GLK-1234-10TH8E10-21 71-D
I need to give to a variable the value GL-1234 (the substring between the 2nd dash and the 4th). I tried

`x=Mid(string, 10, 8)`

but the problem is that not all the strings have the same length, however the only constant is that the substring that i want is between the 2nd and the 4th dash.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `InStr` to find the position of the dashes.

Comment: Thank you!!!! it was exactly what I needed! :)
p.s. New in VBA

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a particular part of a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543225/how-to-get-a-particular-part-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, although I don't think it is the most elegant or the easiest solution:

```
x = ""
p1 = InStr(1, string, "-")
If p1 <> 0 Then
    p2 = InStr(1 + p1, string, "-")
    If p2 <> 0 Then
        p3 = InStr(1 + p2, string, "-")
        If p3 <> 0 Then
            p4 = InStr(1 + p3, string, "-")
            If p4 <> 0 Then
                x = Mid(string, p2 + 1, p4 - p2 - 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: a solution that is more general (ie not relying on finding a certain number of dashes ) would be better

Comment: The question relates to getting a substring that is specifically between the 2nd and 4th dash. How would you get it if you don't rely on there being at least 4 dashes?

Answer (score 9):

Split the string and extract what you want:

```
Dim dataSplit() As String
Dim dataString As String

dataSplit = Split(Sheet1.Range("C14").Value2, "-")

dataString = dataSplit(2) & "-" & dataSplit(3)
```

Comment: +1 Efficient approach. For completeness should have a uBound test on the Split to ensure the required parts are present

Answer (score 0):

this will return 2nd dash and 4th dash, B1 is string : ABC-1234-GLK-1234

```
=MID(B1,FIND("-",B1,FIND("-",B1)+1),FIND("-",B1,FIND("-",B1,FIND("-",B1,FIND("-",B1)+1)+1)+1) - FIND("-",B1,FIND("-",B1)+1))
```