# Take only part of a string in VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel

So I have this string in Excel: MS15-077[3077657]

and I just want to take the first part, MS15-077 to use to compare against other strings. Is there a way to just take the first 8 characters of the cell contents and set that as a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: `Mid(s,1,8)` should work

Comment: Yes - use `Left$(Range("A1").Value, 8)` in VBA or `=LEFT(A1,8)` as a formula.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a particular part of a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543225/how-to-get-a-particular-part-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `Mid`:

If `s = "MS15-077[3077657]"`

Then `Mid(s,1,8) = "MS15-077"`

Or, as Rory pointed out, `Left` works as well and is specifically tailored for extracting substrings which appear on the left of the original string.