# How to find the text between two values in a string?

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, vba

I currently have a cell("Filename"). This returns `H:\F0791\Purchase Requisitions\[PCS.xlsm]`.

I would like to single out the 'F0791' Value. I have previously used MID functions however, this does not work if 'F0791' is a different length.

Would it be possible to call up the values between the first two '\'s or is there a better alternative?

I am seeking this in both formula state and VBA. This is different to other questions because they do not offer a formula alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a particular part of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543225/how-to-get-a-particular-part-of-a-string)

Comment: It's not unique; you just didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another formula approach is to use this formula `=MID(A1,4,FIND("----",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","----",2),1)-4)` in cell `B2` in case your strings are in column `A`

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly thanks. please can you inform me how this would work with the following File name, excel sometimes decides to switch to this one!        \\tbcontract\contracts\F0791\Purchase Requisitions\[PR01.xlsm]Purchase Requisition

Comment: then please use this formula `=MID(A1,24,FIND("----",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","----",5),1)-24)`

Comment: then you can combine it with if formula to extract data from both types of string. `=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))>4,MID(A1,24,FIND("----",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","----",5),1)-24),MID(A1,4,FIND("----",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","----",2),1)-4))`

Answer (score 3):

You could use this UDF, that uses the [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
 On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
 EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 2)), Separator)(n - 1)
 Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    MsgBox "ERROR: Verify if the data exists, example if the separator is correct."
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And this is a test in VBA

```
Sub test()

Text = "H:\F0791\Purchase Requisitions[PCS.xlsm]"
Debug.Print EXTRACTELEMENT(CStr(Text), 2, "\")
End Sub
```

And you could also add it to a Cell, If E1= "H:\F0791\Purchase Requisitions[PCS.xlsm]"  Then you add this to the desired result cell.

On cell F1, this formula:`=EXTRACTELEMENT(E1;2;"\")` gives the result on the image below:
[image: Example]

Or open the insert function window
[image: Insert Function Window]

#### Optional, Description for UDF

This [code adds a description](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/user-defined_function_argument_descriptions_in_excel_2010/) for the UDF. You must run it once.

```
Sub DescribeFunction()
   Dim FuncName As String
   Dim FuncDesc As String
   Dim Category As String
   Dim ArgDesc(1 To 3) As String

   FuncName = "EXTRACTELEMENT"
   FuncDesc = "Returns the nth element of a string that uses a separator character"
   Category = 7 'Text category
   ArgDesc(1) = "String that contains the elements"
   ArgDesc(2) = "Element number to return"
   ArgDesc(3) = "Single-character element separator (spc default)"

   Application.MacroOptions _
      Macro:=FuncName, _
      Description:=FuncDesc, _
      Category:=Category, _
      ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe add some error control in case of a UNC path that starts with `\\`. Seems it could be done by converted the Txt parameter to Txt = Mid(Txt, 2).

Answer (score 0):

For a formula approach, the following worked for me, given that the "filename" cell is in `A1`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("\",A1)+1,((FIND("\",A1,FIND("\",A1)+1))-(FIND("\",A1))-1))
```

This basically finds the position of the first "\" and the second "\" and uses the `mid()` function to pull the string between the two "\"s.

Answer (score 0):

=MID(A2, FIND("\", A2)+1, FIND("\", A2, 4) - 4)

This worked for me assuming that the structure is more or less the same except with regard to the length of the code.