# VBA printing a substring from a string

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to print each substrings in between the "..." from this string: "...covid...is...very...scary" in consecutive cells in a column in excel.

this is my code in VBA.

```
Sub copyd()

findandcopy("...covid...is...very...scary")     'not sure how to print in consecutive cells of a column
 
End Sub
```

```
Function findandcopy(brokenstr As String) As String
 
Dim first, second As Integer
Dim strtarget as string

strtarget = "..."
 
Do until second =0.   'second=0 so that loop ends when there is no more "..." found

  first = InStr(brokenstr, strtarget)
  second = InStr(first + 3, brokenstr, strtarget)
  findandcopy = Mid(purpose, first +3, second - first -3)      'referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543225/how-to-get-a-particular-part-of-a-string#_=_
  first = second         'so that loop can find next "..."
Loop

 
End Function
```

can anyone please advise? thank you for your help :)

Comment: Have a look to the `Split`-command - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyd()
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    ' get splitted text into horizontal array arr()
    arr = Split("...covid...is...very...scary", "...")
    
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then ' if there is something in the array, display it on the sheet
        ' put onto sheet values from transposed array arr()
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1"). _
            Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, why not just split the string by "..."?

Like:

```
Function findandcopy(brokenstr As String, targetStr as string)

dim substr()    

if instr(1, brokenstr, targetStr, vbTextCompare) > 0 then
    'brokenstr has at least one instance of targetStr in it

     brokenstr2 = split(brokenstr,targetStr)
     
     if brokenstr2(0) = "" then
         redim substr(ubound(brokenstr2)-1)
         iStart = 1
     else
         redim substr(ubound(brokenstr2))
         iStart = 0
     end if

     for i = iStart to ubound(brokenstr2)
         substr(i-iStart) = brokenstr2(i)
     next i

else

    'No instances of targetStr in brokenstr
    redim substr(0)
    substr(0) = brokenstr

end if

findandcopy = substr

end function
```

Which will return an array of strings which are the bits between targetStr. Then you can do with it as you please within the parent sub.

If you start doing comparisons with the results and find issues - you can remove whitespace by modifying above as:

```
substr(i) = trim(brokenstr2(i))
```

and your calling code:

```
Sub main()
Dim covid as string
Dim remove as string

covid = "...covid...is....very...scary"
'covid = "really...covid...is...very...scary" 'For testing
remove = "..."
rtn = findandcopy(covid, remove)
```

end sub

Comment: That's very clear! This is my sub to call the function, but it gives me an error that says ByRef Argument type mismatch: 
Sub main()

Dim covid, remove As String

covid = "...covid...is...very...scary"
remove = "..."

Call findandcopy(covid, remove)

End Sub
May I know why my calling of the function was wrong?

Comment: Dim covid as string & DIm remove as string on two separate lines. Also spotted typo on my solution, I'd stargetStr instead of targetStr. Amended above. And I'm also going to amend in case split starts with an empty entry on substr(0)